# FlywayException: Incomplete statement

Tags: stored-procedures, hsqldb, flyway

I can't get **Flyway 7.7.3** to parse the **HyperSQL** CREATE PROCEDURE statement below. Though it used to work I guess, with an older version, as this is a 2018 script that I'm trying to resurrect.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_findByLastname(IN name VARCHAR(30)) READS SQL DATA
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
  BEGIN ATOMIC
    DECLARE persons_by_lastname_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT * FROM persons WHERE last_name = name;
    OPEN persons_by_lastname_cursor;
  END;
```

I unsuccessfully tried to inline the different lines, to get rid of the "DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1" line, and couldn't understand what I read from inside the parser in step-by-step debug mode neither.
This is the complete trace :

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to parse statement in db/migration/V2__procedure.sql at line 1 col 1. See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/knownparserlimitations for more information: Incomplete statement at line 1 col 1...
```

The referred limitations doesn't seem to apply: I tried to change the variable's name.

I also tried to change the delimiter, still no luck!

```
DELIMITER /;
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_findByLastname(IN lastname VARCHAR(30)) READS SQL DATA
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
  BEGIN ATOMIC
    DECLARE persons_by_lastname_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT * FROM persons WHERE last_name = lastname;
    OPEN persons_by_lastname_cursor;
  END/;
```

Comment: The statement is supported by HyperSQL. The issue seems to be in Flyway. Try making the declaration into one line by replacing the line breaks with spaces.  If it still returns an error on the DYNAMIC keyword, try rewriting the procedure as a FUNCTION that returns a TABLE.

Comment: That's right @fredt ; and the statement works under generic schema.sql db init. As said before, the inline of the statement doesn't fix the issue, so it doesn't seem to be an end of line problem. I'll give it another try, though

Comment: Raised as an issue for investigation: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3284